# VB Check a Only Exactly Number in Textbox

Tags: vb.net

Take a look at this picture. - http://www.imagebam.com/image/f544011007926944

I want to check in Textbox1, in the textbox2 enter the number and if there is that number I will appear in another text box. the problem occurs when in textbox1 there are numbers like 10,11, if I enter textbox2 number 1 then it will be taken as such, it will appear as if there is the number 1. I will only use for numbers from 1 to 80 .

where am I wrong?

```
  ' Split string based on space
        Dim textsrtring As String = TextBox1.Text
        Dim words As String() = textsrtring.Split(New Char() {" "c})
        Dim found As Boolean = False
        ' Use For Each loop over words
        Dim word As String
        For Each word In words
            If TextBox2.Lines(0).Contains(word) Then
                found = True
                If CheckVar1.Text.Contains(word) Then
                Else
                    CheckVar1.Text = CheckVar1.Text + " " + TextBox1.Text()
                End If
            End If
```

Comment: Can you improve your question? It's kind of hard to get exactly what you need... but if I'm not wrong, you're treating the numbers as letter and that's why if you write "1" you will get matches like "11" because it's a letter and not a number.

Answer (score 0):

So I think I know what you want. Your issue is the Compare Function on a String is comparing string literals and not numbers '11' contains '1' and '1' for Compare will return true that it contains a '1' in it. You need to convert the strings to numbers and then compare the numbers to each other.

```
Private Sub CompareNumbers()

    'First Textbox that is to be used for compare
    Dim textBox1Numbers As List(Of Integer) = GetNumbersFromTextLine(TextBox1.Text)

    'Second Textbox that is to be used for compare
    Dim textBox2Numbers As List(Of Integer) = GetNumbersFromTextLine(TextBox2.Text)

    'Union List of Common Numbers (this uses a lambda expression, it can be done using two For Each loops instead.)
    Dim commonNumbers As List(Of Integer) = textBox1Numbers.Where(Function(num) textBox2Numbers.Contains(num)).ToList()

    'This is purely for testing to see if it worked you can.
    Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
    For Each foundNum As Integer In commonNumbers
        sb.Append(foundNum.ToString()).Append(" ")
    Next

    MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString())

End Sub

Private Function GetNumbersFromTextLine(sTextLine As String) As List(Of Integer)

    Dim numberList As List(Of Integer) = New List(Of Integer)()

    Dim sSplitNumbers As String() = sTextLine.Split(" ")

    For Each sNumber As String In sSplitNumbers

        If IsNumeric(sNumber) Then
            Dim iNum As Integer = CInt(sNumber)
            If Not numberList.Contains(iNum) Then
                numberList.Add(iNum)
            End If
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Non Numeric Found in String :" + sTextLine)
        End If

    Next

    Return numberList

End Function
```

Comment: Worked... Thanks a lot for the code, with this code the lottery program will be almost done: D The program will know how to recognize the winning numbers from a text file and a lot of combinations.